# Access Denied in a Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, server, citrix, invoke-command

i hope you can help me. I got a problem with my Script for the automation of the Citrix Optimizer. The scenario:
I got a Server A where i want to execute my Script.
And a Server B (Core Server --> file server) where the Citrix Optimizer tool is saved.
And a Server C (just for testing, when its final it should execute it on round about 50 XENAPP Servers) where the Citrix Optimizer should be installed resp. executed.

```
$Program= "\\xxx\xxx\xxx\CitrixOptimizer\CtxOptimizerEngine.ps1"
$computer= Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(name=*xxxxxxxxxxxxx*)" -SearchBase "OU=xxxxxxxxxx,OU=CVAD1912,OU=Server,DC=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,DC=xx"
$computername=$computer.name


foreach ($server in $computername){

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{

Start-Process $using:Program}
    
}
```

This is my Script so far.
And the error is:

```
Access Denied
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-Process], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
    + PSComputerName        : xxxxxxxxxxx
```

If someone got an idea how to solve that for me unsolvable riddle. Please help me. I'm really new to PowerShell and I don't want to quit already xD.

note: there are some places where it is just filled up with xxxx. This is just due to security reasons not to leak any sensitive data.

Comment: Your local credentials aren't forwarded to the remote session, so there's no credentials available for the remote machine to use when trying to authenticate you against `\\xxx\xxx`. Classic [double-hop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Open Powershell ISE with Run as administrator and execute the same

Comment: following up on Mathias comment above, you can take a look at the different permissions passed onto that session using a simple `whoami /groups` on your session first, then another `icm {whoami /groups} -cn 'adfsdf'` on the remote system.

Comment: Okay Guys to be honest, at the moment I'm completely overwhelmed. I don't get it what i need to do right now. @MathiasR.Jessen which of these solutions would you recommend? In the post you've sent me. There are several selections.

Comment: @cosmo_ That depends entirely on your environment, and the remoting targets. Do you trust the remote computers (ie. only other engineers in your company has admin access to them)? One option (not listed in the article) is to copy the file from the share to the remote machine _before_ using `Invoke-Command` - this way the executable will be available locally and you therefor won't need to access the share.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen All servers which I'm going to updates are trustfully. Your option to copy the file from the share to the remote machine is not possible bcs i want to install it on every server with just one click. To be clear it is that "double-hop" problem but i don't know how to evade it.